# Wix Installer - Add custom dialog to WixUI_Minimal

Tags: wix

Please note - I don't want to change anything in WixUI_Minimal(if possible).

I am trying to add a custom dialog(UserTypeDlg) after WelcomeEulaDlg in WixUI_Minimal i.e whenever a user clicks on Install button after accepting license. This part works fine

On custom dialog I have provided back button which works just fine and takes me to WelcomeEulaDlg. However, when I again click on Install button it directly start installation with out showing my custom dialog.

Could someone help me to get around this?

My code is -
    Custom dialog
        
      
        
          
          
          -->

```
      <Dialog Id="UserTypeDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup" NoMinimize="yes">
        <!--<Control Id="InstallButton" Type="PushButton" Text="Install" Height="17" Width="56" X="245" Y="243">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
        </Control>-->
        <Control Id="UserTypeRadioGroup" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="UserTypeRadioButtonGroup" Height="100" Width="100" X="50" Y="50">
          <RadioButtonGroup Property="UserTypeRadioButtonGroup">
            <RadioButton Value="1" Text="Admin" Height="17" Width="50" X="50" Y="0" />
            <RadioButton Value="2" Text="Domain User" Height="17" Width="100" X="50" Y="20" />
          </RadioButtonGroup>
        </Control>
        <!--<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="245" Y="243" Width="100" Height="17" Text="Next">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
        </Control>-->
        <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" >
          <Publish Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="Update">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
          <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <!--<Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.WelcomeDlgBitmap)" />-->
        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)">
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeEulaDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>

      </Dialog>

      <!--<Dialog Id="AdminDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup" NoMinimize="no">
      </Dialog>-->
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Product installation file:-

```
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI Id="UserTypeUI">
      <Property Id="UserTypeRadioButtonGroup" Value="2" />
      <!--<TextStyle Id="Tahoma_Regular" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
      <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="Tahoma_Regular"/>-->

      <Dialog Id="UserTypeDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup" NoMinimize="yes">
        <!--<Control Id="InstallButton" Type="PushButton" Text="Install" Height="17" Width="56" X="245" Y="243">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
        </Control>-->
        <Control Id="UserTypeRadioGroup" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="UserTypeRadioButtonGroup" Height="100" Width="100" X="50" Y="50">
          <RadioButtonGroup Property="UserTypeRadioButtonGroup">
            <RadioButton Value="1" Text="Admin" Height="17" Width="50" X="50" Y="0" />
            <RadioButton Value="2" Text="Domain User" Height="17" Width="100" X="50" Y="20" />
          </RadioButtonGroup>
        </Control>
        <!--<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="245" Y="243" Width="100" Height="17" Text="Next">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
        </Control>-->
        <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" >
          <Publish Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="Update">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
          <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <!--<Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.WelcomeDlgBitmap)" />-->
        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)">
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeEulaDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>

      </Dialog>

      <!--<Dialog Id="AdminDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup" NoMinimize="no">
      </Dialog>-->
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wix documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations/#inserting-a-custom-dialog-into-a-built-in-dialog-set) you still need to change the '' elements of what you want to change, setting the 'Next Event' and 'Back Event' of your dialog and overwriting the events of elements that should come before and after your dialog